# Can Python running on a server interact with the user's OS?

Tags: python, flask, server, operating-system, pywin32

Is it possible for a Python program/app running on a server interact with a user's operating system on the client side? Say for instance if I had a Flask App running on a server, would it be possible for that app to use something like PyWin32 to interact with the user's Windows (Outlook, Excel, etc)? If so, how could this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you feel knowing that every website you visit can do things like that on your computer? ;) No, flask cannot do anything like that, but you can implement a client which connects to flask and lets it do whatever you want to let it do.

Comment: My god, I hope the answer to this is no.  Do you realize how big a security hole this would be?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are you referring to a web application on the client side executing in a browser? If so, then OS interaction will be limited to the permissions of the web browser and the privileges the browser grants to client side code execution. If you're talking about an executable running on the client that can connect to a server, then in theory any amount of OS interaction is possible only limited by the permissions granted to the executable. This second way of OS interaction from client to server is quite common.